# how to stop shrinking the image and navbar when it is mobile responsive

Tags: jquery, css

Hi I have a navbar when the page is scrolled down it will get shrink and when it is at the top it will be in the normal. I tried to shrink the navbar and image using the below `jquery` code

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('a.navbar-brand img').css({
            'height': '30'
        });
    } else {
        $('a.navbar-brand img').css({
            'height': '60'
        });
    }

});
```

the issue is when it is mobile responsive I don't want any shrinking of the navbar and I tried the below code but it didn't work

```
if ($(window).outerWidth() > 768) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('a.navbar-brand img').css({
                'height': '50'
            });
        } else {
            $('a.navbar-brand img').css({
                'height': '100'
            });
        }

    });
}
```

How do I achieve this

Comment: Try adding class on scroll and then use media query to style as you want instead on inner css styles via jquery

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like this.

```
if ($(window).outerWidth() > 768) {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
            $('a.navbar-brand img').css('height','50%');
        } else {
            $('a.navbar-brand img').css('height','100%');
        }
    });
}
```

Hopefully it is helpful